# Is it feasible to combine --span-hosts with --no-parent in wget?

Tags: wget

I have pages on a site that are a directory of a huge amount of links to another site. I don't want to download anything from the origin site that is the parent of such directory. I prefer to download everything from the `--span-hosts --domains targetsite.com`, though.

Will the `--no-parent` cause a conflict on the target site? Could the target site be limited to some "parent" there, especially if it has a similar URL structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no problem in combining `--span-hosts` along with `--no-parent`. They both work on different links and it is indeed a very common usecase to pass both of these switches together.

`--span-hosts` allows Wget to follow links that are on a different domain, whereas `--no-parent` will constrain Wget to retrieve links on the current domain to only those whose directory path is deeper than the current directory.